# A bigger curly bracket in the system of equations

Tags: equations, fontsize, brackets

I'm using Lyx and I need to type this system of these two questions. The problem is that I know almost nothing of TeX so I use a script a friend of mine wrote for me:

```
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{x+y}-0.34=\frac{y}{x+y+3}\\
\frac{y}{x+y}-0.17=\frac{y}{x+y+1}
\end{cases}
```

**Problem**: what I don't like about that script and its outcome is that the equations inside the curly bracket get smaller if you compare them with the first two equations in the screenshot.

[image]

**What I want**: I want to have the equations inside the curly bracket to be the same size as the first two ones in the screenshot. I guess for that I need a bigger curly bracket or some other magic which I do not possess. How can I do that?

Comment: Just use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

Comment: @Werner you're a genius, thank you!

Comment: You also have the `dcases` environment  from `mathtools` (displaystyle cases).